# question envolving homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $P = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \geq 0, y \geq 0 \}$ and $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y\geq0\}$. Prove that $P$ and $S$ are homeomorphics.

I have tried to build a contínuous and bijective function $f:S\to P$. My first attempt was $f(x,y) = (\vert x \vert,y)$. This function is contínuous but not injective. Then I tried $f(x,y) = (e^x,y)$, but there is no $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = (0,y)$. So I arrived in $f(x,y) = (|x|e^x,y).$ When I was trying to find the inverse I realized that this function ins't injective again...

Can you help me?

Comment: In my opinion, it's easier to see a homeomorphism if you consider the regions $P$ and $S$ in polar form (or, even better, as their canonical images in the complex plane)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Take polar coordinates of the points involved, and simply double/half the angle.
**Bonus:** Do you know which maps do these correspond when points $(x,y)$ are viewed as complex numbers $x+yi$?

Comment: I know that if $(x,y) \in P$ then $(x,y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ for $0 \leq  \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} $. And for $S$, we take $\theta \in [0,\pi)$, how can I build this function???

Comment: $f: P \to S$, $f(x,y)= (x \cos y, x \sin y)$???

Comment: As mentioned, in this method, you simply double the angle, so the map is $$P \to S : (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) \mapsto (r\cos(2\theta), r\sin(2\theta))$$
Just check it's a well-defined continuous bijection (with a continuous inverse also identifiable in polar form)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\mathbb R^2$ is nothing else than the complex plane $\mathbb C$. We have $P = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \text{Re}z \ge 0, \text{Im}z \ge 0 \}$ and $S = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \ \text{Im}z \ge 0 \}$. Define
$$\phi : P  \to Z, \phi(z) = z^2 .$$
You can easily check that this has all desired properties. The easiest way to do this is to use polar coordintaes ($z = re^{it}$ with $t \in [0,2\pi)$).